# Android: Unable to use animated GIF in layout. (Guide followed)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, animated-gif

I followed [this guide](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/)  for how to incorporate an animated gif into an Android application layout.

My GIFView java file is as follows:

```
package com.example.bilisattendancerecorder;

public class GIFView extends View {

private Movie mMovie;
private long movieStart;
private int gifId;

private void setAttrs(AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (attrs != null) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.GIFView, 0, 0);
        String gifSource = a.getString(R.styleable.GIFView_src);
        //little workaround here. Who knows better approach on how to easily get resource id - please share
        String sourceName = Uri.parse(gifSource).getLastPathSegment().replace(".gif", "");
        setGIFResource(getResources().getIdentifier(sourceName, "drawable", getContext().getPackageName()));
        a.recycle();
    }
}
public GIFView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initializeView();
}
public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setAttrs(attrs);
    initializeView();
}
public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setAttrs(attrs);
    initializeView();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    if (movieStart == 0) {
        movieStart = now;
    }
    if (mMovie != null) {
        int relTime = (int) ((now - movieStart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, getWidth() - mMovie.width(), getHeight() - mMovie.height());
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
public void setGIFResource(int resId) {
    this.gifId = resId;
    initializeView();
}
public int getGIFResource() {
    return this.gifId;
}
private void initializeView() {
    if (gifId != 0) {
        InputStream is = getContext().getResources().openRawResource(gifId);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
        movieStart = 0;
        this.invalidate();
    }
}}
```

My XMl layout is as follows.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".Main" >

<com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.widget.GIFView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    components:src="@drawable/loading_66_drk" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hellogoodbye"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Checking..."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/biliswhite"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="161dp"
  android:layout_height="46dp"
  android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Atrrs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="GIFView">
        <attr name="src" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The logcat says the following, however it's worth noting that I would only hit an error adding the short "widget" in the gifView declaration in the layout xml file. Priot to this however no GIF was drawn. Is there something I overlooked?

```
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bilisattendancerecorder/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.Main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.widget.GIFView
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.widget.GIFView
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.Main.onCreate(Main.java:159)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    ... 11 more
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.widget.GIFView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
09-25 16:28:50.590: E/AndroidRuntime(19830):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
```

Any real help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. I've been trying to insert a gif for the last 4 hours and the only (limited) success I had was with a webview. (I decided this wasn't the method for me due to loading times).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. bacause your package name is `package com.example.bilisattendancerecorder;`

but your entered in your xml like `com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.widget.GIFView`

that's why that `ClassNotFoundException` came..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:components="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
tools:context=".Main" >

<com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.GIFView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    components:src="@drawable/loading_66_drk" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hellogoodbye"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Checking..."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@color/biliswhite"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView1"
  android:layout_width="161dp"
  android:layout_height="46dp"
  android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I've left the office but I can test it tomorrow. However that does look identical to how it was when no gif was being drawn.